# Helm Chart - How to set configMap from values.yaml?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a file `application.yaml` from my spring configuration. I want to reuse this file in ConfigMap. I defined these properties in Helm's `values.yaml` and then reading them in `configmap.yaml`.

Here are all the files:

**application.yaml**

```
invoice:
  catalog-service-uri: http://catalog-service
spring:
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://invoice-postgres/invoice_order
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://invoice-postgres/invoice_order
  rabbitmq:
    host: invoice-rabbitmq
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://ecomm-keycloak/realms/EcommRealm
```

**values.yaml**

```
configMapData:
  application.yaml: |-
    invoice:
      catalog-service-uri: http://catalog-service
    spring:
      flyway:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://invoice-postgres/invoice_order
      r2dbc:
        url: r2dbc:postgresql://invoice-postgres/invoice_order
      rabbitmq:
        host: invoice-rabbitmq
      security:
        oauth2:
          resourceserver:
            jwt:
              issuer-uri: http://ecomm-keycloak/realms/EcommRealm
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: order-config
  labels:
    app: order-service
data:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.configMapData }}
    {{ $key }}: |-
      {{ $value | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

With this configuration, I am getting error:

**msg: 'error unmarshalling resource: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 7:
did not find expected node content'**

What's wrong with this configuration?
Is there any better way of doing the same?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are some of the names like `invoice-postgres` and `invoice-rabbitmq` local to this chart; do they depend on the Helm release name?  I might consider writing this YAML structure directly into the ConfigMap template and computing its values, rather than passing the whole thing as values.  Setting individual environment variables like `SPRING_FLYWAY_URL` is another reasonable option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: order-config
  labels:
    app: order-service
data:
  {{- .Values.configMapData | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Andromeda works fine. An alternate, if you want to use the `application.yaml` file directly.

Place the file in your `helm-chart/` directory (not inside `templates`).

`configmap.yaml:`

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: order-config
  labels:
    app: order-service
data:
  application.yaml: |-
{{ .Files.Get "application.yaml" | indent 4 }}
```

This shall produce the same result. Hope this helps!

Comment: With this configuration, I am getting error: stderr: "Error: YAML parse error on order-service-helm/templates/configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: did not find expected key\n\nUse --debug flag to render out invalid YAML\n"

Comment: It totally works for me. I have even tried to move `application.yaml` file into a `files` directory in the `helm-chart/` directory and refer to it as `{{ .Files.Get "files/application.yaml" | indent 4 }}`, it still works. Not sure how to reproduce the error you get.